# Converting nested object to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 Response::json function and having trouble with passing an object.
I have an object of User, containing some other objects - Account and Settings.
I tried to cast the object to array, but the internal objects (Account and Settings) stay as object.
Is there an easy way to convert a nested object to array so I can pass it on to Response::json?

Comment: Can you post some code and a dump of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(array)$object
```

to convert the object to an array. However, unless the class provides a specialized method for this, it will only return the public properties.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel converts Objects automatically when using Response::json. So usually you wouldn't have to bother:

```php
Response::json($user);
```

In case you really need an array, you can do this:

```php
$user->toArray();
```